# Packing multiple parameters into one inside Spring MVC Controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Is there an easy way to pack multiple parameters from the URL into a single unit and send it to a Spring MVC Controller?

I have more than 20 parameters and it is inconvenient to type `@RequestParam` for each of them.

Also, how we can I handle a varying number of parameters, e.g if I have some list of info that varies in size?

Answer (score 0):

This is what [Spring's MVC's `@ModelAttribute` annotation](http://www.captaindebug.com/2011/11/using-spring-mvcs-modelattribute.html) is used for. You can place all your parameters on a bean and move that around instead.

When you submit your form, Spring binds the request parameters into your bean and it [works also with list parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12123432/how-to-bind-a-dynamic-list-of-fields-in-a-jsp).